ERROR DOMException: String contains an invalid character
HTML file
<div>
    <header>Login Page</header>
    <p><b>{{title}}{{text}}</b></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="onClickMe($event)">Info</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <rating [rating]="5"></rating>
    <div *ngFor="let catpicture of getPictures">
        <!-- {{catpicture}} -->
        <catpicture [data="catpicture"]></catpicture>
    </div>
</div> 

Login Component file
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { catPicture } from './login.loginname';

@Component({
  selector: 'catpicture',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.scss',
  providers: [catPicture]
})

export class LoginComponent {
  title = "My First Angular App";
  text = " World";


  onClickMe($event: any) {
    console.log("Clicked",$event);
  }

  getPictures;
  constructor(catPicture:catPicture){
    this.getPictures=catPicture.getPictures();
  }
  
  // @Input()data:any
}

Loginname.ts
export class catPicture{
    getPictures(){
        return [
            {
            imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=1",
            pictureName: "Product 1",
            postDate: "May 31, 2018",
            description: "Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida...",
            rating:4
            },
            {
                imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=2",
                pictureName: "Product 2",
                postDate: "May 31, 2018",
                description: "Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida...",
                rating:3
            },
            {
                imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=3",
                pictureName: "Product 3",
                postDate: "May 31, 2018",
                description: "Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida...",
                rating:3
            },
            {
                imageUrl: "http://loremflickr.com/150/150?random=4",
                pictureName: "Product 4",
                postDate: "May 31, 2018",
                description: "Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida...",
                rating:3
            }
        ];
    }
}

catpicture.ts
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
// import { getCatpictures } from './login.canpicture';

@Component({
    selector:'catpicture',
    template:`
    <div class="media">
        <img class="mr-3" src="{{data.imageUrl}}" alt="GeneralPicture">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="mt-0">Title</h5>
            {{data.postDate}}
            <br>
            {{data.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    styles:[`
        .media{
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
    `]
})

export class catPicture{
    @Input() data: any;
}

module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MovieComponent } from './movie/movie.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { catPicture } from './login/login.loginname';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    MovieComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [catPicture],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

and the HTML page show like this:enter image description here

ERROR DOMException: String contains an invalid character

So I go back to check HTML code file, but unfortunate I don't know how to fix this bug since very simple, but I'm a beginning learner, could anyone tell me how to do? Thanks everyone!!
How can I do?

[data="catpicture"] seems to be a typo

In First HTML file Below line needs to corrected.
<catpicture [data]="catpicture"></catpicture>



<catpicture [data="catpicture"]></catpicture>

change to <catpicture [data]="catpicture"></catpicture>

Thx, but in vscode it still error and show :
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'catpicture'.ngtsc(-998002)
login.component.ts(8, 20): Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
(variable) catpicture: { imageUrl: string; pictureName: string; postDate: string; description: string; rating: number; }

Solved
HTML file should be this:
<div>
    <header>Login Page</header>
    <p><b>{{title}}{{text}}</b></p>
    <!-- <ul> -->
        <!-- <li *ngFor="let loginname of loginnames">
            {{loginname}}
        </li> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="onClickMe($event)">Info</button>
    <br>
    <rating [rating]="3"></rating>
    <br>
    <rating [rating]="5"></rating>
    <!-- <div *ngFor="let catpicture of getPictures">
        <catpicture [data]="catpicture"></catpicture>
    </div> -->
    <div *ngFor="let picture of getPictures">
        <img [src]="picture.imageUrl" alt="{{ picture.pictureName }}">
        <p>{{ picture.pictureName }}</p>
        <p>{{ picture.postDate }}</p>
        <p>{{ picture.description }}</p>
        <p>Rating: {{ picture.rating }}</p>
    </div>//if return object, should following HTML format type
</div> 


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
